# Regex detect if entire string is a placeholder

Tags: java, regex, placeholder

I am trying to write a regex which should detect
"Is the entire string a placeholder".

An example of a valid placeholder here is `${var}`
An example of an invalid palceholder here  is `${var}-sometext` as the placeholder is just a part of the text

The regex I have currently is `^\$\{(.+)\}$`

This works for normal cases.
for example

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ${var} | Regex Matches | Expected ✅ |
| 2 | ${var} txt | Regex Does Not Match | Expected ✅ |

even works for nested placeholders

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ${var-${nestedVar}} | Regex Matches | Expected ✅ |

Where this fails is if the strings begins and ends with a placeholder
for eg

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | ${var1}-txt-${var2} | Regex Matches | NOT Expected ❌ |

Basically even though the entire string is not a placeholder, the regex treats it as one as it begins with `${` and ends with `}`

I can try solving it by replacing `.+` with something like `[^$]+` to exclude dollar, but that will break the nested use case in example 3.

How do I solve this?

EDIT

Adding some code for context

```
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\$\\{(.+)\\}$");
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(placeholder);
boolean isMatch = matcher.find();
```

Comment: Is this in bash? Can you show us some sample code to give us some context?

Comment: It's in java. have updated question with some code
@AndyLester

Comment: Java regex does not allow recursing a part of a pattern, you will have to write some code for this to work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my regex does not need to detect all nested placeholders.. 
so that is not a problem for me. 
The regex just needs to detect if the entire string is a placeholder (it may or may not contain nested placeholders)

Comment: "*it may or may not contain nested placeholders*" is the culprit.

Comment: If you *really* want to build regex based solution then start here: http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html. But better hire good security team if your code will need to be maintained by people who know where you live.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I think you need to avoid greedy quantifier:

```
\$\{(.+?)\}
```

Notice the `?` after `+` which are reluctant quantifier: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

That should match `${var1}-txt-${var2}`

Now, if you use `^` and `$` as well, this will fail.

Note that you could also use [StringSubstitutor from commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) to perform a similar job (it will handle the parsing and you may use a `Lookup` that capture the variable).

**Edit for comment**: given that Java regex don't support recursion, you would have to hard code part of recursion here if you wanted to match all your 4 cases:

```
\$\{([^{}-]+)(?:|-\$\{([^{}-]+)\})\}
```

The first part match a variable, ignoring `{}` and `-`. The other part match either an empty default value, either an interpolation.

If you need to catch `${a-${b-${c}}}` you would have to add another layer which you should avoid: doing complex regex for the sake of doing complex regex will simply be a maintenance ache (with only one level of recursion the regexp above is hard to read)

If you need to handle recursion, I think you get no other alternative do it yourself with code as as below:

```
void parse(String pattern) {
  if (pattern.startsWith("${") && pattern.endsWith("}")) {
    // remove ${ and }
    var content = pattern.substring(2, pattern.length() - 2 - 1);
    var n = content.indexOf('-');
    String leftVar = content;
    if (n != -1) {
      leftVar = content.substring(0, n); 
      // perform recursion
      parse(content.substring(n+1)); 
    } 
    // return whatever you need
  }
```

Or use something that already exists.

Comment: I AM actually using a class which extends StringSubstitutor to inject some custom logic. Hence the need for manually parsing. 

As for the non-greedy matching, it will work for  example #4  but it will break example #3. as that example contains a nested placeholder

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean isPlaceHolder(String s) {
    return s.matches("\\$\\{[^}]*\\}");
}
```

or optimized for several uses:

```
private static final Pattern PLACE_HOLDER_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^}]*\\}");
static boolean isPlaceHolder(String s) {
    return PLACE_HOLDER_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

- A **matches** does a match from begin to end, so no need for: `^...$`. As opposed to **find**.
- It still is tricky to detect as false: `"${x}, ${y}"`. It would be best when the placeholder is just for a **variable**, `\\w+`.

Comment: Based on OP example: `3 ${var-${nestedVar}} Regex Matches Expected ✅`. Current solution will not accept `${var-${nestedVar}}` as valid match.

Comment: @Pshemo yes though `${var-nestedVar}` is what I encountered in EL. My code would say false on the entire string, true on the second (=nested) placeholder, which should be evaluated first à la "reducible expressions."

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to match arbitrarily deep nested structures using regular expressions. The most you can do with a single regex is match a finite number of nested parts, though your pattern will probably be pretty ugly.

Another approach is to apply a simpler pattern many times, until you have an answer. For example:

1. Replace everything that matches `\$\{[^}]*\}` (or `\$\{.*?\}`) with nothing (the empty string)
2. Repeat until the pattern no longer matches

If the string is now empty, then the value was "valid".
If the string is not empty, then the value is "invalid".

```java
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?\\}");

public boolean isValid(String value) {
  while (true) {
    String newValue = PATTERN.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
    if (newValue.equals(value))
      break;
    value = newValue;
  }
  return value.isEmpty();
}
```